# mypy "Optional[Dict[Any, Any]]" is not indexable inside standard filter, map

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, mypy

Given the following code:

```py
from typing import Optional, Dict

def foo(b: bool) -> Optional[Dict]:
    return {} if b else None


def bar() -> None:
    d = foo(False)

    if not d:
        return

    filter(lambda x: d['k'], [])
```

mypy 0.770 fails with the following error on the last line of `bar`: `Value of type "Optional[Dict[Any, Any]]" is not indexable`. Same goes for `map`. Changing the line to use list comprehension or `filter_` or `map_` from pydash resolves the error.

Why does mypy throw an error when using the standard `filter` even though there is a type guard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type-narrowing that happens after an `if` or `assert` doesn't propagate down to inner scopes that you've bound that variable in.  The easy workaround is to define a new variable bound with the narrower type, e.g.:

```
def bar() -> None:
    d = foo(False)

    if not d:
        return
    d_exists = d

    filter(lambda x: d_exists['k'], [])
```

The reason that `d` isn't bound to the narrower type in the inner scope might be because there's no guarantee that `d` might not get changed back to `None` in the outer scope, e.g.:

```
def bar() -> None:
    d = foo(False)

    if not d:
        return

    def f(x: str) -> str:
        assert d is not None  # this is totally safe, right?
        return d['k']         # mypy passes because of the assert

    d = None  # oh no!
    filter(f, [])
```

whereas if you bind a new variable, that assignment is not possible:

```
def bar() -> None:
    d = foo(False)

    if not d:
        return
    d_exists = d

    def f(x: str) -> str:
        # no assert needed because d_exists is not Optional
        return d_exists['k']

    d_exists = None  # error: Incompatible types in assignment
    filter(f, [])
```

In your particular example there's no runtime danger because the `lambda` is evaluated immediately by `filter` with no chance for you to change `d` in the meantime, but mypy doesn't necessarily have an easy way of determining that the function you called isn't going to hang on to that lambda and evaluate it at a later time.

Comment: Does that mean that `filter_` works because `mypy` understands that the lambda gets evaluated before anything else has a chance to modify `d`, and `filter` doesn't work because it constructs an iterator and `mypy` doesn't have an easy way to know how that iterator works?

Comment: I'm not positive because I'm not familiar with pydash at all, but I suspect `filter_` "works" because it's untyped (or poorly typed) and so the expression is never typechecked at all.  It's not hard to simply disable type checking by using untyped interfaces.  I'd have to actually see an example of it in action to have a better answer.

Comment: I see. I think the possibility that the lambda won't be invoked until later is the answer, then, and also explains why list comprehension works.

Comment: Yes, with list comprehension you aren't binding a lambda that's going to hang around for an indeterminate length of time.  If you had a filtering function that worked similarly (say something where you passed it `(d.get, 'k')` rather than `lambda x: d['k']`) then that would also avoid the issue.

Answer (score 8):

`mypy` doesn't simulate the code: it doesn't know that `d` is not `None` if the call to `filter` is actually reached. It only knows that there is an attempt to index something that was *statically* tagged as possibly having `None` as a value. (Put another way, the static type of `d` doesn't change unless you actually assign a value with a different static type.)

You can help `mypy` by using the `cast` function.

```
from typing import Optional, Dict, cast

def foo(b: bool) -> Optional[Dict]:
    return {} if b else None


def bar() -> None:
    d = foo(False)

    if not d:
        return

    d: dict = cast(dict, d)  # "Trust me, mypy: d is a dict"

    filter(lambda x: d['k'], [])
```

Comment: I could be misunderstanding something still, but I don't think this explains why using list comprehension or `filter_` works without giving mypy additional hints.